# Microsoft Access SQL Joins

Tags: ms-access

List all players and their ages for their associated current team for teams that have a manager.

Here are my 3 Tables and their attributes

```
PLAYER
PLAYERNUM Primary Key
PLAYERNAME
PlayerAge

TEAM
TEAMNUM Primary Key
TEAMNAME
TeamCity
MgrNum

AFFILIATION
PLAYERNUM Primary Key/Foreign Key
TEAMNUM Primary Key/Foreign Key
AffilYrs
AffilBatAvg
AffilDateStart Foreign Key
AffilDateEnd
AffilCurrentTeam
```

Here is my SQL:

```
    SELECT PLAYERNAME, PlayerAge
    FROM PLAYER INNER JOIN AFFILIATION
    ON PLAYER.PLAYERNUM = AFFILIATION.PLAYERNUM
    INNER JOIN TEAM
    ON AFFILIATION.TEAMNUM = TEAM.TEAMNUM
    WHERE MgrNum IS NOT NULL;
```

I am given the error missing operator in query expression

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? You tagged mysql and sql server but in the question you mention Access.

Comment: My bad, you're correct I am using MS Access

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your query. Is this the exact SQL you are using, or have you changed field names for the internet/example/sample? Can you bring this query up in Design view or is throwing an error when switching to the GUI?

Comment: It was giving me errors when I attempted to switch to the Design view. this is the exact SQL I was using. I added parentheses like Rainman mentioned below. But it returns duplicate values from the tables now. How would I get rid of the duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it should be;

```
    [NotTested]
    SELECT PLAYERNAME, PlayerAge
        FROM (PLAYER INNER JOIN AFFILIATION
        ON PLAYER.PLAYERNUM = AFFILIATION.PLAYERNUM)
        INNER JOIN TEAM
        ON AFFILIATION.TEAMNUM = TEAM.TEAMNUM
        WHERE MgrNum IS NOT NULL;
        GROUP BY PLAYER.PLAYERNAME, PLAYER.PlayerAge
```

You should use parentheses for multiple joins in access.

Comment: This runs but gives me duplicate values. How would I get rid of duplicates?

Comment: Are you sure that your table design is correct ? Seems like there is a n-n relationship between them. By the way, you can group PlayerName and PlayerAge. I updated my answer.

Comment: The only reason you'd get duplicates is if a player has multiple affiliations. should a player be on multiple teams or affiliations?    (could just add keyword `distinct` after select but that seems to hide a potential problem.)